# Codenameone: Unable to call service from simulator

Tags: codenameone

When I called the service from my application on the simulator I get following errors.

```
WARNING: Apple will no longer accept http URL connections from applications you tried to connect to http://localhost:8080/myapp/Login to learn more check out https://www.codenameone.com/blog/ios-http-urls.html
Rendering frame took too long 1804 milliseconds
```

Can you please let me know how to resolve it? My application needs to be supported on all platforms (Andriod, IOS, Windows) and I don't want to write native code for all platforms separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link within the warning: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/ios-http-urls.html

Clearly explains that Apple expects you to use https and not http for all communications. That means you need to setup an https server for your service access.